# query joins give me repreated results mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query in mysql that return me repeated results i want results unique.e.g in my example i have company name it return me repeated name,id.

```
SELECT 
      company.name,
      company.id,
      branchInfo.name,
      branches.visible 
FROM branches  
INNER JOIN users branchInfo ON branches.branchId=branchInfo.id 
INNER JOIN users company ON branches.companyId=company.id   
WHERE branches.visible=1
```

it returns me the multiple time repeated data so i want it unique.

Comment: use `distinct` or `group by`

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Calling `users` something like `branchInfo` is highly suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/distinct-optimization.html) or [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), they are not the same but in your example you will get the same results.

Use DISTINCT if you just want to remove duplicates. Use GROUPY BY if you want to apply aggregate operators like: AVG, MAX, MIN, SUM, and COUNT

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  company.name,
  company.id,
  branchInfo.name,
  branches.visible 
FROM branches  
INNER JOIN users branchInfo ON branches.branchId=branchInfo.id 
INNER JOIN users company ON branches.companyId=company.id   
WHERE branches.visible=1 
GROUPY BY company.name
```

Or this:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(company.name),
  company.id,
  branchInfo.name,
  branches.visible 
FROM branches  
INNER JOIN users branchInfo ON branches.branchId=branchInfo.id 
INNER JOIN users company ON branches.companyId=company.id   
WHERE branches.visible=1;
```

> **Group by** : clause is used in collaboration with the SELECT statement to arrange identical data into groups. This GROUP BY clause
>   follows the WHERE clause in a SELECT statement and precedes the ORDER
>   BY clause.
>
> **DISTINCT** keyword is used in conjunction with the SELECT statement to eliminate all the duplicate records and fetching only unique
>   records.

**UPDATE**

Regarding your question about joins.

[image]

Comment: Which one did  you use?  What results did you get?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;GROUPY BY branchInfo.id&#039; at line 1

Comment: ok, seems something is wrong with the query syntax, could you please paste your query here.

Comment: @MuhammadirfanMayo seems like you copied some strange characters, and that is the reference to &#039 in the error code. Make sure to remove all strange characters, you could for instance paste the code into notepad, sublimetext, etc before runnning this.

Comment: can you tell me bro when i'm using inner why it's giving me repeated. i'm using first left join for this now i changed all to the inner so now im getting the one record. i'm not sure now issue was with left.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join multiple times `user` table. instead, you can write as below:

```
SELECT 
      company.name,
      company.id,
      branchInfo.name,
      branches.visible 
FROM branches  
INNER JOIN users branchInfo ON branches.branchId=branchInfo.id AND branchInfo.id = branches.companyId    
WHERE branches.visible=1
```

Comment: Then show me your table structure and I'll give you best query using that